# Ipywidgets: why widget without value attribute has value equal to None during debugging?

Tags: ipywidgets

I've just run debugger and saw something weird:
[image]

`grid` is an instance of GridBox with some children, exactly like debugger displays. But why I was able to run line with `widget.value = 1`, when it is GridBox which doesn't have `value` attribute?